# "Wrong" time delta calculation in python datetime package

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta, dst

What value do you expect to be
`26-Mar-2023 8AM Amsterdam time` - `25-Mar-2023 8AM Amsterdam time`? 
Day-light-saving is on since 26-Mar-2023 in Amsterdam, so 25-Mar is in UTC+1 and 26-Mar is in UTC+2, intuitively either `23 hours` or `25 hours`, but not `24 hours` because of the DST shift...

But the below calculation shows 24 hours, why is that?

My python version is 3.9.6

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pendulum

p1 = datetime(year=2023, month=3, day=25, hour=8, minute=0, tzinfo=pendulum.timezone('Europe/Amsterdam')) # No DST
p2 = datetime(year=2023, month=3, day=26, hour=8, minute=0,  tzinfo=pendulum.timezone('Europe/Amsterdam')) # DST

print((p2 - p1).total_seconds()/3600)
```

I tried to use `pytz` or `pendulum`, results are the same, 24 hours.

I convert those two time points to UTC, or just use the unix timestamp, I got 23 hours, as I expected.

```py
(p2.astimezone(pendulum.timezone('UTC')) -  p1.astimezone(pendulum.timezone('UTC'))).total_seconds()/3600
```

Or

```py
(p2.timestamp() - p1.timestamp())/3600
```

Comment: Python's timedelta arithmetic is wall time arithmetic, so in my opinion, 24 hours is correct. To get the 23 hour you expect, convert to UTC, which has no DST.

Comment: See also https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/02/aware-datetime-arithmetic.html for some background information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifying `tzinfo` doesn't correctly create the timezone-aware datetime object for timezones that have daylight-saving transformations<sup>See [docs](https://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic)</sup>. Printing the `repr` of your `p1` and `p2` shows that both `p1` and `p2` have the same timezone:

```
print(repr(p1))
# datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 25, 8, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Amsterdam' LMT+0:18:00 STD>)
 
print(repr(p2))
# datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 26, 8, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Amsterdam' LMT+0:18:00 STD>)
```

You need to pass the timezone-unaware datetime object through `timezone.localize`.

```
import pytz

tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Amsterdam')

u1 = datetime(year=2023, month=3, day=25, hour=8, minute=0)
u2 = datetime(year=2023, month=3, day=26, hour=8, minute=0)

a1 = tz.localize(u1)
a2 = tz.localize(u2)

print(repr(a1))
# datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 25, 8, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Amsterdam' CET+1:00:00 STD>)

print(repr(a2))
# datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 26, 8, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Amsterdam' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)

print((a2 - a1).total_seconds() / 3600)
# 23.0
```

---

Alternatively, create `pendulum.datetime` objects:

```
p1 = pendulum.datetime(year=2023, month=3, day=25, hour=8, minute=0, tz=pendulum.timezone('Europe/Amsterdam')) # No DST
p2 = pendulum.datetime(year=2023, month=3, day=26, hour=8, minute=0,  tz=pendulum.timezone('Europe/Amsterdam')) # DST

print((p2 - p1).total_seconds()/3600)
# 23.0
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for pointing it out! Is this some kind of known issue? The tzinfo impacts the unix timestamp and converting to utc.

Comment: @D.Zhai see https://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic Specifying `tzinfo` in the constructor is safe for timezones without daylight saving transformations

Comment: @FObersteiner, I tried with ZoneInfo, same issue.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Did you try this with zoneinfo as well? I think pytz actually disrespects Python's timedelta rules here, because of its own timezone model.

Comment: @D.Zhai I think this is expected. See my comment on your question.

Comment: @FObersteiner `tzinfo=ZoneInfo('Europe/Amsterdam')` gives the same result, which makes sense -- wall-time arithmetic should return 24 hours, but IM (relatively uninformed) O `timedelta` should use elapsed-time arithmetic for TZ-aware objects, because IM (relatively limited) E we usually care about elapsed time when subtracting two datetimes.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi It *should*, I agree... but I think it doesn't, see Paul's blog post I linked under the question. So I don't think this is about setting tzinfo correctly; pytz is "right" for the wrong reason ;-)